# What is the minimum requirements for installing the published application in windows form .NET?

Tags: .net

I'd like to be able to determine what I should list as a minimum system requirements to run my published application in windows(laptop) in terms of RAM, CPU, etc.

What I have tried:

I've tried to search all over the internet but i cant find a solution for my questions. please help

*note: the application i publish is e-commerce but offline*

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86863/how-are-minimum-system-requirements-determined

Answer (score 0):

Test your application on a minimum configuration machine or setup a virtual machine and test your application there. Some of the parameters you can test:

Is it generally slow when performing regular operations (excluding memory usage) then increase processor requirements.

Does it require diskspace beyond the app footprint such as for file handling? List that.

Does it cause a lot of disk swapping? If so, you need more RAM.